# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)' on FreeBSD

Tags: mysql, sockets, system, freebsd, mysql-error-2002

Hello guy's i have this problem :

```
root@Myname:~ # mysql -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
root@Myname:~ # chown -R mysql /var/db/mysql
chown: mysql: illegal user name
root@Myname:~ #
```

I do not know how to fix this please help

System operations : FreeBSD 9.2 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've only installed the mysqlXX-client port instead of the server. To install the server (assuming 5.6), you can use the [ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html) system:

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql56-server
make install
```

If you haven't installed the ports tree, first run:

```
portsnap fetch
portsnap extract
```

To ensure it gets started up on a reboot, you would enable it using the [rc.conf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+2.2.8-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) system:

```
echo 'mysql_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf.local
```

And then you can start it up:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
```

Let me know if that gets you to where you need to be.